# Can't connect to SQL Server DB from SSMS network error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Here some background on the setup. The app server and the db server are on a workgroup no domain. Both are AWS EC2 instances. A partner went and install an evaluation copy of SQL Server 2014. I apply the licence key (SQL Server 2014 Standard) on the instance and run the upgrade wizard since then nothing is working as it should. Before the expired date you could connect to the SQL server from the app server using the SSMS. Now getting an network error 18456.

Firewalls are disabled
Under the SQL Configuration manager TCP/IP have been enable.
Can telnet form the APP server to the SQL server on port 1433 and 1434
Can login with my sql user using SSMS on the SQL server it self

I had a look at these websites as will but still no luck.
https://logicalread.com/errors-sql-server-login-failures-pd01/#.WsNZsIhuZEY
http://sqltechtips.blogspot.co.za/2018/03/sql-server-login-failed-error-18456.html

Sorry I am not an DB admin. Any help will be greatly appreciated
Gerrit

Comment: Hi Haidar, thanks for your reply. I know which error is saying password mismatch. I have reset passwords create an new user with a simple password still the error is the same with State 8 password mismatch. The SQL server is set to Windows and SQL Authentication mode otherwise this would not work before, the evaluation period expired correct? I am lost to why it will not connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said that the SQL Server Error code : `18456` is coming with state: `8`.

Mostly the Error code : `18456` with state : `8` coming due to **user authentication**.

As per MSDN Blog [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/02/21/understanding-login-failed-error-18456-error-messages-in-sql-server-2005/) `the key to the message is the 'State' which the server will accurately set to reflect the source of the problem`.

**For Troubleshooting Error 18456**

As **`SQLBlog`** of **@AaronBertrand** [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456) ,  you can find out every error details with description , based on their **state** with Error code: `18456`.

### After Edit

As **`SQLSERVERLEARNER`** Blog [here](http://sqlserverlearner.com/2011/microsoft-sql-server-error-18456)  the

> Error Number: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 1

may have so many reasons.

**Reasons for this error:**

1. User does not have access on the server
2. Provided user name is wrong
3. Provided Password is Wrong
4. Using windows login credentials for SQL Server authentication
5. Login for the user is disabled
6. Login was successful but access to the server failed
7. Problems with SQL Service
8. Password for the user has to be changed
9. User does not have access to perform the specified acton on the
   server, Only has limited access
10. User does not have previlages to access the specific database,
     agent service etc
11. Even here MSDN BOL here
     mention that for `State : 1` , Error information is not available.
     This state usually means you do not have permission to receive the
     error details. Contact your SQL Server administrator for more
     information.
12. As [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456)
     State 1 now occurs when a login is disabled – but actually, the
     error in the log is 18470, not 18456 – because the login is
     disabled, it doesn't get that far.  See state 7. Prior to SQL
     Server 2005, State 1 always appeared in the log for all login
     failures, making for fun troubleshooting. The login is disabled
     *and* the password is incorrect.  This shows that password validation occurs first, since if the password is correct and the
     login is disabled, you get error 18470 (see state 1 above). It's
     possible that your application is sending cached credentials and
     the password has been changed or reset in the meantime – you may
     try logging out and logging back in to refresh these credentials.

For further your ref [here](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/16/sql-server-v-next-denali-contained-databases) and [here](https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/10/sql-server-v-next-denali-more-on-contained-databases-and-contained-users)

Comment: @Gerrit, As now you said you are getting the Error Number: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 1. There will be so many reasons , i am updating the answer again according to your Error message.